# How to run a continuous thread in WEB API like we have continuous threads in Desktop Applications that runs 24/7

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm dealing with a situation where I've a REST Service written in C# and hosted on IIS Web Server.
Everything is smooth and the service is being consumed for required reasons and functioning.
Now I have a requirement that needs to be incorporated in the same service, I need to call a stored procedure after every 1 minute to check database for any new data available in my table, and if my stored procedure returns a row, I need to send this data by making call to another REST Service hosted somewhere else. Now the hurdle is that, I have no experience regarding how to run a continuous thread in WEB API that runs continuously 24/7 and checks database after every 1 minute for any update.

Now where to define this thread as REST Service is based on a stateless architecture, i mean how to indulge this requirement in my WEB API Project.

**I though of doing this like starting a thread in my WebApiConfig.cs**

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        **//DB check thread
        AsyncClass a = new AsyncClass();
        a.StartThread();**

        config.EnableCors();
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

**My Async Class looks like this:**

```
 public class AsyncClass
{
    CDCService serObj = new CDCService();
    public void StartThread()
    {
        var ActLog = new ActivityLog("019");
        ActLog.Info("DB check thread started");
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serObj.CheckDbAsync();
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
        });
        task.Start();
    }
}
```

**And my DB Call looks like this**

```
 public void CheckDbAsync()
    {
        ActivityLog ActLog = new ActivityLog("019");
        ActLog.Info("Entering Checking DB ASYNC");
        TradingAccount accObj = new TradingAccount();
        var result = dbproc.GetTradingAccount().ToList();
        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            //ActLog.Info("Count is greater than 0");
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                accObj.userId = userName;
                accObj.password = password;
                accObj.brokerShortCode = item.BrokerShortCode;
                accObj.cnicNicopPoc = item.CnicNicopPoc;
                accObj.clientCode = item.ClientCode;
                accObj.accOpeningDate = item.AccountOpeningDate;
                accObj.status = item.Status;
                accObj.remarks = item.Remarks;
                accObj.reserved = item.Reserved;

                SendTradingAccountInfo(accObj);
            }
        }
        //ActLog.Info("Exiting Checking DB ASYNC");
    }
```

However, this practice doesn't seems to be a valid one, what should I do to resolve this problem and how to cater this change within my WebApi so that i don't have to write another separate service for this.

Comment: You'll need a scheduler of some sort in your app. Check out [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Comment: This has been answered multiple times. In fact, someone asked the same thing a few hours ago. The docs show how to [use a BackgroundService for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Desktop and web applications are completely different. In a web application there are no long-lived threads. Each request is handled by its own thread, retrieved from a threadpool thread. Creating a thread IIS knows nothing about [can lead to weird errors and corrupted data](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) when IIS decides to recycle an app pool.

Comment: You can't do this in old-school web API, you will need a separate Windows service. In ASP.NET Core you can use a BackgroundService as was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a Windows service to cater to this need, since I've understood that web apps do not work like this, and they have their limitations, now I'm doing it with a background Windows service.